# A curious chain of Markov events

Tags: markov-chains, independence

Consider a Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ that is discrete in time with transition matrix $P$ and whose state space is $S:= \{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4 \}$. Define for any $s\in S$ the *first passage time* $T_s$ as the random variable $$T_s := \inf \{ n \geq 1: X_n=s \}.$$
Fix some $n_0$. How can I prove that $\{ T_s = n_0\}$ is independent of the future event $\{ X_{n_0+3} \in \{ s_2,s_4 \} \}$?

Comment: Do you really mean $\{ T_s = n_0 \}$? What does that mean? Do you mean to say that for all $s \in S$, the two events $\{ T_s = n_0 \}$ and $\{ X_{n_0+3} \in \{s_2,s_4 \} \}$ are independent?

Comment: @Peter Yes, for each fixed state $s$ independence should hold, I believe. They key I think is that the event $\{ T_s = n_0 \}$ should be independent of all future events, but I'm happy with a specific example of a future event, to make things more concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The independence of the two events is not given, as the following example illustrates.

- $Pr[X_1 = s_1] = 1$
- $Pr[X_{n+1} = s_2 | X_n = s_1] = 1/2$
- $Pr[X_{n+1} = s_3 | X_n = s_1] = 1/2$
- $Pr[X_{n+1} = s_2 | X_n = s_2] = 1$
- $Pr[X_{n+1} = s_3 | X_n = s_3] = 1$
- $Pr[X_{n+1} = s_4 | X_n = s_4] = 1$

This Markov chain goes to states $s_2$ or $s_3$ with probability 50%, respectively. Then, it stays there forever.

In this example, we have $T_{s_2} = 1 \iff  X_4 \in \{ s_2, s_4\}$, hence the two events are not independent.

Comment: Nice example. But wouldn't it have been more correct to say $X_4=s_2$? While using "$\in$" is not wrong, it is less precise, since the Markov chain can't ever reach $s_4$.

Comment: In my Markov chain, the two are equivalent: $X_4 = s_2 \iff X_4 \in \{ s_2, s_4\}$. Since you were asking about the event $X_4 \in \{ s_2, s_4\}$, I used that in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see (I was just looking at the "$\Longrightarrow$" direction).