# Sweet independence of my first passage time.

Tags: markov-chains, independence

*Consider the following definition and example of a stopping time: [image]*

*In my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275470/a-curious-chain-of-markov-events?noredirect=1#comment4680642_2275470), a concrete example of a Markov chain is given in the answer, such that first passage time RV is **not** independent of all $X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\ldots$, which is what I took to be the formal way of defining this. Is the copied excerpt therefore wrong? Or have I made an error somewhere?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excerpt is the correct definition. The source of confusion seems to be in the wording ``Depends only on $(X_0,\dots,X_n)$". This is to be understood that the event $\{T=n\}$ is determined by $X_0,\dots,X_n$:  knowledge of  $X_0,\dots,X_n$ determines $T=n$ or not.  Nevertheless, this does not imply independence of the said events on  $X_{n+1},\dots$, simply because $X_{n+1},X_{n+2},\dots$ are not, in general, independent of $X_0,\dots,X_n$.

Comment: Are you saying $\{ T=n\}$ is a function of $(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$, i.e. $\{T=n\} = f(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$? Because "depends on" is very vague wording - and especially dangerous in probability theory, where it can mean probabilistic dependence as well as functional dependence (the latter implying the former).

Comment: $\{T=n\}$ is a set. It is not equal to a function. The correct statement is the indicator of $\{T=n\}$ is a function of $X_0,\dots,X_n$.

Comment: I'm still confused about what the formal statement of the definition is (sorry about the late response, I was busy). Is it "**We call the RV $T$ a *stopping time* iff  there exists a function $f$ and a fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbf{1}_{\{T=n\}}=f(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$**" ? Because you also say "knowledge of $X_0,…,X_n$ determines $T=n$ or not" and I'm not sure how to interpret that, because a sentence of the form "$A$ may depend on $B$ - or not"  does not have any information content.

Comment: The exact definition is the following. For each $n$,  the event $\{T=n\}$ is an element in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_0,\dots,X_n$. This is equivalent to ${\bf 1}_{\{T=n\}}$ being a function of $X_0,\dots,X_n$ (the function depends on $n$), which is the same as $\{T=n\}$ being determined by $X_0,\dots,X_n$. Hope this helps.